# Print doc with iPhone application

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am a new iPhone Application developer. I want to create an application which will print a document or string  by a button tap.After tapping the button search the printer which is in network path.iPhone device and printer will be connected with wireless LAN. I read the Apple guideline to create such type of application, but I am so new a developer that I don't understand all of this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find this tutorial http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=115 helpful.